# Lua Function Not Doing Anything

Tags: c++, lua

I finally was able to get Lua running with my compiler using C++. I now tried starting some tutorials and the first program won't do anything. I downloaded the code they used and it still did nothing. No errors however. Test prints out fine but I get no response from the luaL_dostring. I am using v5.1.4-46. Is it possible that i installed it incorrectly in some way that doesn't result in errors? I printed out the memory address of the lua state and that seems to be working. If someone could give me some sample code to run I would really appreciate it.

Here's the code:

```
#include <lua.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    cout << "Test" << endl;

    luaL_dostring(L, "print(\"Hello from Lua!\n\")");

    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Honestly had no idea that existed. All accepted now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dostring syntax generates invalid Lua code... "\n" gets passed to lua parser before execution. you need a "\\n"... think so. So your "luaL_dostring" error code is actually a syntax fault. funny thing...

you should not use dostring for more than testing.

Comment: Thanks for the response but that didn't do anything. Even removing lua_close() completely does nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed everything. Funny how the code i got directly from the tutorial didn't work... I'll probably try some other tutorial if that happens again. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, actually its logic.. but not so obviously. It took me a moment to understand :) In case of errors, check return values. cheers.